# Insert into Access DB Table though C#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Can anybody please tell me what I am doing wrong here? **It gives me Invalid Insert INTO exception.**

```
internal static bool CheckInKey(string keyID, int cabinetID, int drawerNumber, string row, int column)
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "Insert into CheckInCheckOut(KeyID,CabinetID,DrawerNumber,Row,Column,CheckInTime) values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", keyID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", cabinetID);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", drawerNumber);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", row);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", column);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("?", DateTime.Today.ToString());

    conn.Open();
    int rowsAffected = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    conn.Close();

    if (rowsAffected == 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Here is my Access Table snapshot:
[image]

Comment: CheckInTime is a DateTime, why do you pass a string?

Comment: I think that even when using the ? placeholder syntax you want to give your parameters actual names in adding them.

Comment: is CheckOutTime NULLABLE??

Comment: Thank you all for you help. I got it fixed. Column is a reserved keyword, that was the issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COLUMN` is a reserved [keyword in MS-Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/access-2007-reserved-words-and-symbols-HA010030643.aspx).
To use it from C# code you need to encapsulate it in square brackets

```
cmd.CommandText = @"Insert into CheckInCheckOut
                         (KeyID,CabinetID,DrawerNumber,Row,[Column],CheckInTime) 
                         values(?,?,?,?,?,?)";
```